# How do I publish an Angular-CLI project as an NPM module?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm making my own Angular 2 module with Angular-CLI. How to prepare module to `import`? How do I publish the final output to NPM for use with other Angular2 projects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've managed to publish my project to npm.
Here's what I did.

In `angular-cli` project my module went to single folder (`component-warpper`).
In that folder I've added `index.ts` with list of modules and components to export.
I also added `package.json` file (screenshot).

Then in command line go to this folder and `npm publish`.
Now I can import it as `node_modules` in other projects.

[image]

Comment: do we need a type definition file(*.d.ts) as well?

Comment: There is a post and sample code [here](https://www.usefuldev.com/blog/post/publishing-a-library-from-an-angular-cli-project) showing how to isolate a module in an Angular-cli project and publish it as an npm package which might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a question about how to publish an Angular2 NgModule made with Angular-CLI to NPM. More info on publishing to NPM can be found at https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers, however the specifics for Angular-CLI projects and Angular 2 modules are beyond me as I have not published Angular2 modules to NPM before.

---

The `import { MyModule } from 'package/myModule';` style imports are for published packages on NPM and resolve by checking for the required files in local and global `node_modules` folders. You could emulate this by publishing an empty package to NPM then using the link command to link your code, but I would consider that abuse of NPM's services as you go around their private package solution. If this is a public module, remember to only release when necessary, and use a `link`ed version for development.

To import a module from your project you need the relative path, something more like `import { MyModule } from './myModule/my.module';`.

Comment: And how to prepare ng module for npm? Is there some kind of tutorial?